# DBCC SHOWCONTIG returns 2 row against certain tables in one environment and 1 row in another environment

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I am seeing that in 2 different SQL 2016 envs one is returning 1 row against DBCC SHOWCONTIG and in other 2 rows against the same table. Why would this be happening? Both the servers are on SQL2016 SP2-CU2 and the table structure too is similar. Any clue on why this would be happening?

Example:

**Env 1**

```
ObjectName  ObjectId    IndexName   IndexId Level   Pages   Rows    MinimumRecordSize   MaximumRecordSize AverageRecordSize ForwardedRecords    Extents ExtentSwitches  AverageFreeBytes    AveragePageDensity  ScanDensity BestCount   ActualCount LogicalFragmentation    ExtentFragmentation

Table_x 1116450251  col_st_idx  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0
Table_x 1116450251  col_st_idx  1   0   515 24376   41  328 148.876 0   68  70  88.058  98.9120583148011    91.5492957746479    65  71  1.16504854368932    10.2941176470588
```

**Env 2**

```
ObjectName  ObjectId    IndexName   IndexId Level   Pages   Rows    MinimumRecordSize   MaximumRecordSize   AverageRecordSize   ForwardedRecords    Extents ExtentSwitches  AverageFreeBytes    AveragePageDensity  ScanDensity BestCount   ActualCount LogicalFragmentation    ExtentFragmentation

Table_x 1075131221  col_st_idx  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0
```

Comment: did not mean to confuse, what I meant was the SQL server edition and that is nearly same for the 2 environments.
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU3) (KB4458871) - 13.0.5216.0 (X64)- returns 1 row
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU13) (KB4549825) - 13.0.5820.21 (X64)- returns 2 rows.

Both of them are on SQL Server 2016 ,so unable to figure out why would the output be different, so anything you can provide would be very helpful.

Comment: I had mistakenly mentioned CU2 in the header, please ignore that part, the correct versions are mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: DBCC SHWCONTIG is deprecated.  Can you reproduce this using sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats ?